# Natural language Processing using TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer, nlp

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
filename='train1.txt'
dataset=[]
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        dataset.append([str(n) for n in line.strip().split(',')])
print (dataset)
tfidf=TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf.fit(dataset)
dict1=tfidf.vocabulary_
print 'Using tfidfVectorizer'
for key in dict1.keys():
    print key+" "+ str(dict1[key])
```

I'm reading strings in file train1.txt. But when trying to execute the statement tfidf.fit(dataset),its resulting in an error. I'm unable to fix the error completely.Looking for help.

Error Log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Q1.py", line 52, in <module>
    tfidf.fit(dataset)
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1361, in fit
    X = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).fit_transform(raw_documents)
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 869, in fit_transform
    self.fixed_vocabulary_)
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 792, in _count_vocab
    for feature in analyze(doc):
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 266, in <lambda>
    tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 232, in <lambda>
    return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: Post the error log, please

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit) for TfidfVectorizer, the `fit` function expects "an iterable which yields either str, unicode or file objects" as its first argument. You're providing it a list of lists, which does not satisfy this requirement.

You've turned each line into a list of strings using the `split` method, so you either need to rejoin the string, or avoid splitting it at all. This depends on your input format, of course.

It should work if you modify the line

```
dataset.append([str(n) for n in line.strip().split(',')])
```

Depending on your input format, you  might need to replace it with something like

```
dataset.append(" ".join([str(n) for n in line.strip().split(',')]))
```

or simply

```
dataset.append(line.strip().replace(",", " "))
```

(I can only guess about the usage of "," in your input text).